# Со вчера / Со вчерашнего дня

Tags: грамотная-речь

Она не пила пива *со вчера.*
Она не пила пива *со вчерашнего дня.*
Какой из вариантов является правильным, если говорящий подразумевает календарный день, а не время суток?

Answer (score 1):

(1) *Она не пила пива **со вчерашнего дня**.*

(2) *Она не пила пива **со вчера**.*

**ВЧЕРА**, I. нареч. 1. В день, предшествовавший сегодняшнему дню; накануне. Виделись в. Сегодня жарко, но не так, как в. 2. В недавнем прошлом. Ещё в. он был студентом, и вот уже - учитель. II. неизм.; ср. **День, предшествовавший сегодняшнему**. Назначили встречу на в., а он не пришёл.

Обв варианта употребляются, но **частотность у них разная**: В Нацкорпусе 665:38.
Мне второй вариант кажется **разговорным, чуть ли не просторечным**, но стилевых пометок для него в словаре не дается.

В то же время второй вариант обычно встречается в речи персонажей, поэтому он ближе к разговорному. Литературным вариантом лучше считать  первый вариант.

Comment: К сожалению, и в _авторском тексте_ часто встречается (если гуглом книги посмотреть), при ссылке на передвижения и прочие действия или состояния персонажей.

Answer (score 0):

*Оба* варианта указывают на (вчерашний) **день**. Выражение "со вчера" свойственно разговорному (по моим ощущениям, *сниженному* даже в рамках разговорного) стилю, хотя и часто встречается в современной литературе.

Answer (score 0):

*Она не пила пива со вчерашнего дня.* || Этот вариант звучит очень культурно и грамотно.

Другой вариант звучит сильно резко и кратко. Он хуже. Но бывает, что в смс-ках нужно сделать текст как можно короче, или в комментариях на этом сайте, так как есть лимит на количество символов.